# I want to make the asp.net MVC page configurable, any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, web-parts

guys, I was applied a big task is about to make the MVC page configurable.
It means:
It just like the webpart in webform.
1.We can config the partial view in the view,make the partial view enable or not,we can drag and drop the partial view anywhere in the container.
2.One partial view is related to a simple mode(entity),and also the fields of the form in the partial view can be configurable:enable or not and the position can be adjusted.

now I have some ideas as following:
1.I create an model base, let other models inherit from model base,model base just hold the metadata related to the fields and the model itself.
2.Render the settings which is in model base to hidden field throght html helper and partial view.And on the client, I just use the jquery to handle the layout according to the setting in the hidden field.
3.The partial view I just let it to render only, and the real logic I will hand it on the page which contain the partial view. I think this would be simple and extendable.right?

So any ideas here? I really think this task is complicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, [Omar AL Zabir Blog](http://omaralzabir.com/) has an portal website, called dropthings, maybe it is closed now. He tried to implemented the things like igoogle did. You can see that project at [codeplex](https://dropthings.codeplex.com/).
And you also can find some ideas for that find of application at [Lakkakula's Blog](http://lakkakula.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/developing-web-2-0-portal-using-asp-net-mvc-microsoft-ajax-client-templates-and-jquery-with-drag-and-drop-widget-personalization-part-1/)

Hope this help.